# Google search api - how to search local pages?

Tags: google-api

I use

```
new google.search.WebSearch();
```

and

```
setSiteRestriction(".");
```

It does not work.

I have a bulk of google programming docs in html format, and the search result links to google site, which require a internet connection.

```
devSiteSearcher = new google.search.WebSearch();
devSiteSearcher.setUserDefinedLabel("All Developers Site");
devSiteSearcher.setSiteRestriction("http://developer.android.com/");
```

I just want to search locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use google custom search!~ I forgot where it is...google for it!